# Screen wents black shade on launching hawx 2 in wine (Kali Linux)

Tags: kali-linux, wine, games

I've installed HAWX 2 in Kali Linux using wine. When I launch tha game in dx9 version the screen becomes black shaded including all the Linux UI. It becomes normal only when I restart the PC. The game also crashes on loading screen.[image]

I've took a screenshot and restarted my PC. When I opened the screenshot I took before it looks normal.
[image]

How do I fix this and play the game good?

Comment: Kali is a professional tool for security experts. It has no business being used for games! Why are you trying to do this in Kali?

Comment: I'm a beginner to Linux and I'm starting from kali. It's not about Kali I'm asking this question as common for all Debian Linux OS. And my question is about why a game affect the UI of the os?

Comment: That's just it. It will almost certainly _not_ be common for all Debian-based systems. Please read [this post](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/22222) which explains why Kali should never be used to learn Linux and why it shouldn't be used as a normal operating system. It isn't a normal operating system, it isn't made for beginners and assumes its users are security professionals. Using it to play games is like buying a tractor instead of a car and expecting it to have air conditioning.

Answer (score 4):

Wine isn't magic and if a program uses complex Windows APIs it doesn't work properly. You can't solve every problem, and the one you described [seems to be common.](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28682) Your best bet is to install a Windows VM if you need to play that game.
Also stop using Kali if you don't know how it is properly used. As @terdon told you, it is **not** a desktop OS that should be used for everyday purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Myself a beginner to Kali. Gaming is not a problem but doing everyday purpose makes me learn things about Kali. Actually the reason of my question is how a game affects the total UI of the Linux.

Comment: Please let me know about any books or something to learn about Kali.